# Parse multiple instances of a character

Tags: r, tidyr

Using R, I am trying to parse multiple instances of text out of a character and keep it tied to the associated column. I am able to successfully extract the first instance using str_match, however, I need to do the same thing for the remaining instances. I believe utilizing str_extract_all somehow might be the way to go, but I'm unable to get it to work.

My ideal output would be:

```
Object Id   rule_nbr
6603        1
10891       2
13520       2
15079       2
11085       3
11082       3
23221       4
```

Code creating the dummy data frame is below.

```
# create dummy data set
logic <- c("Blah blah blah (Object Id 6603) = YES (Y)",
"Blah Blah… (Object Id 10891) = Blah, Blah; (Object Id 13520) Blah -+ Blah (Object Id 15079) = Blah Blah---; $",
"Blah Blah (Object Id 11085) = Blah Blah (Object Id 11082) > $ Blah Blah",
"Blah Blah (Object Id 23221) = Blah Blah (Blah Blah) Blah Blah")

rule_nbr <- c("1","2","3","4")
logic <- as.data.frame(logic)
rule_nbr <- as.data.frame(rule_nbr)
x <- cbind(rule_nbr,logic)

# extract Object Id into a new column keeping it with the associated rule_nbr
x$Object_Id <- str_match(x$logic, '\\(Object Id (\\d+)\\)')[,2]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We could do this with `tidyverse`.  Extract the 'Object Id' from the 'logic' column with `str_extract_all` as a `list` column and then `unnest`

```
library(tidyverse)
x %>%
   transmute(rule_nbr,
             ObjectId = str_extract_all(logic, "(?<=Object Id )[0-9]+")) %>% 
   unnest
```